# Program copies and pastes twice

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a macro to allow me to search through my existing worksheets to search under a cell value.

```
If wS.Name = "2012" Or "2013" Or "2014" Or "2015" Or "2016" Or "2017" Or "2018" Or "2019" Or "2020" Then
            lastrow = wS.Cells(wS.Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

            'LastRow means to search till the end
             For r = 2 To lastrow
                    'This will check entire column for value
                    If wS.Range("B" & r).value = Sheets("Query").Range("A2").value Then
                        wS.Rows(r & ":" & r).Copy Sheets("Male").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
                    End If
            Next r
            'Exit For
         End If
         Next
```

The problem I have with the code above is that it copies the row twice. Example:

```
1/1/2000 | 12345 | 100   
2/1/2000 | 12345 | 191   
3/1/2000 | 12345 | 211  
1/1/2000 | 12345 | 100   
2/1/2000 | 12345 | 191   
3/1/2000 | 12345 | 211
```

Comment: yesterday I saw similar question from you, I prepared answer but your post has been deleted:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the first problem of your code is in this line:

```
If wS.Name = "2012" Or "2013" Or "2014" Or "2015" Or "2016" Or "2017" Or "2018" Or "2019" Or "2020" Then
```

Vba doesn't has understanding of such syntax

So, should be:

```
If wS.Name = "2012" Or wS.Name = "2013" Or wS.Name = "2014" Or _
   wS.Name = "2015" Or wS.Name = "2016" Or wS.Name = "2017" Or _
   wS.Name = "2018" Or wS.Name = "2019" Or wS.Name = "2020" Then
```

Or you can use this method:

```
If "|2012|2013|2014|2015|2016|2017|2018|2019|2020|" Like "*|" & wS.Name & "|*" Then
```

Or like this:

```
If wS.Name Like "201[2-9]" Or wS.Name = "2020" Then
```

*Finally*, if I have correct understanding what you want to achieve within your code, then you can use this:

```
For Each wS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If "|2012|2013|2014|2015|2016|2017|2018|2019|2020|" Like "*|" & wS.Name & "|*" Then
    lastrow = wS.Cells(wS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            With Sheets("Male")
                If wS.Range("B" & r).Value = Sheets("Query").[A2].Value Then
                    wS.Rows(r).Copy .Rows(.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1)
                End If
            End With
        Next r
    End If
Next
```